# How to render to a texture instead of FragColor?

Tags: c++, flutter, opengl-es, glsl

I have the following shader which does conversion between YUV color format and RGB:

```
#version 300 es

#ifdef GL_ES
// Set default precision to medium, this is needed for GL_ES (android)
precision mediump int;
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform sampler2D tex_y;
uniform sampler2D tex_u;
uniform sampler2D tex_v;

in vec2 TexCoord;
out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    vec3 yuv;
    vec4 rgba;
    
    yuv.r = texture(tex_y, TexCoord).r - 0.0625;
    yuv.g = texture(tex_u, TexCoord).r - 0.5;
    yuv.b = texture(tex_v, TexCoord).r - 0.5;

    rgba.r = yuv.r + 1.596 * yuv.b;
    rgba.g = yuv.r - 0.813 * yuv.b - 0.391 * yuv.g;
    rgba.b = yuv.r + 2.018 * yuv.g;
    rgba.a = 1.0;

    FragColor = rgba;
}
```

On `FragColor = rgba;` it renders to the available frame buffer. How can I render to a texture generated on C++ instead? I need this because Flutter gives me a texture for rendering into, so I need to somehow render to it instead of outputting to FragColor

The only way I can think is reading from the frame buffer, then writing with glTexImage2D, but can I do it directly on the shader? I don't want to do this additional copy.

Comment: You probably want to look at [framebuffer objects](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Framebuffers).

Comment: On Android, if the YUV surface comes from camera or video pipeline on the phone, import the YUV surface as an EGL external image and use an external image sampler in the shader - then the GPU does the YUV conversion for free. It will be a lot faster than rolling your own YUV conversion.